# Moving LazyFilterSequence out of ForEach into a separate variable results in requires conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

This code works fine

```
ForEach(items.filter({$0.matchesSearch(text: searchText) }), id: \.id) { item in
```

but moving the collection out of the `ForEach`

```
let takenOut = items.filter({$0.matchesSearch(text: searchText) })
ForEach(takenOut, id: \.id) { item in
```

results in this error

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'LazyFilterSequence<Results<T>>.SubSequence' 
(aka 'LazyFilterSequence<Slice<Results<T>>>') conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
```

**any ideas why?**

i need to take the sequence out so i can use it's count

whole code for the context

```
struct SearchSectionView<T: DatabaseItem & Identifiable & SearchMatchingSupport>: View {
    
    @Binding var searchText: String
    
    @ObservedResults(
        T.self,
        where: { $0.recordState == .published }
    ) var items
    
    var body: some View {
         Section("Results") {
             let o = items.sorted(byKeyPath:"name", ascending: true).filter({$0.matchesSearch(text: searchText)})
             ForEach(o, id: \.id) { item in
                 Label(item.suggestionText(), systemImage: "circle").searchCompletion("\(item.id)")
             }
         }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why does assigning the result of `filter` to a `let` constant cause it to no longer work?

### Short Answer:

`filter` returns different results based upon what the receiver expects.

---

### Long Answer

Consider this example:

```
let arr = ["apple", "apricot", "banana", "pear"]

let filtered = arr.lazy.filter { $0.hasPrefix("a") }

func count(arr: [String]) -> Int {
    arr.count
}

// This works
count(arr: arr.lazy.filter { $0.hasPrefix("a") })
      
// This doesn't work
count(arr: filtered)
```

Here it is running in a Playground.  When filter is passed directly to `count`, it works.  When filter is assigned to the constant `filtered`, it doesn't work when passed to `count`.

[image: playground showing the error]

---

### So, what is going on here?

In the first call to `filter`, it returns a `LazyFilterSequence<String>`.

[image: playground showing filter returning a LazyFilterSequence]

---

When passed to `count` which is expecting a `[String]`, `filter` returns a `[String]`.

[image: playground showing filter returning an array of String]

---

To make this example more similar to your case, let's make `count` generic:

```
func count<T: RandomAccessCollection>(arr: T) -> Int {
    arr.count
}
```

[image: Playground showing RandomAccessCollection error]

Now, like `ForEach`, `count` is expecting something that adopts `RandomAccessCollection`.  In this case, Swift still chooses the version of `filter` that returns an `Array`:

[image: Playground example with RandomAccessCollection]

---

### Conclusion

The conclusion is, there are different versions of `filter`, and the one you get is based upon the expectations of the receiver.  In this example, when the result was assigned to `filtered`, Swift returned a version that required the least up front work.  That way, if only the first item in the result is needed, a lot of work is saved.

In the second case where we are passing the filtered result to `count()`, Swift does the extra work to turn the result back into an `Array` which is what `count` expects.

In your case, `ForEach` expects something that adopts `RandomAccessCollection`.  Swift chooses a version of `filter` that returns a value that adopts that protocol.

*Note:*

You can use `let` to store the search result, you just need to give your `constant` the explicit type that is passed to `ForEach`. For example, in my case:

```
let filtered: [String] = arr.lazy.filter { $0.hasPrefix("a") }

count(arr: filtered)  // this now works
```

[Option]-click on your call to `filter` to find the type that `filter` is returning and then use that type in your `let` statement.

Comment: this answer is magnifico!!! thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

This filtering shouldn't be in the view, move it to your model, so that the view's model becomes `sortedAndFilteredStuff` and not *stuff that the view has to then process itself*.  You'll get errors, sometimes hard-to-understand errors, if you put regular swift code inside a `ViewBuilder` block.

Comment: from what i read in the realm docs, this is the way how they intended the filtering, since @ObservedResults works proper only on SwiftUI views / structs

Comment: The ObservedResults property wrapper is ok, that is making the var your view's model, but I believe you need to make it filtered like @ObservedResults(... filter: NSPredicate(format: "...")) var items. idk about sorting

Comment: that would be ideal, but you cannot use self variables :( "Cannot use instance member 'searchText' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"